# Adding a new type of field to an existing table

Tags: mysql

I have a table `Details` It has 2 fields `Name` and `Country`. It currently has 5 rows, with the values of `Country` as A,B,B,C,D. I need to add a new field `State` for the rows that `Country` is B . Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A table's design is fixed, regardless of the data. If you want to add a column, it will apply to all rows.

```
ALTER TABLE `Details` ADD COLUMN `State` VARCHAR(12) NULL; -- 12 was just a guess
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add one column for a single row, that's not how relational databases work. However, you can either add a column for the whole table and set to null the rows where you don't have any data, or create a separate table to store your states.

For instance:

```
CREATE TABLE state (detail_id integer, state_name varchar(50));
INSERT INTO state (detail_id, state_name) VALUES ((SELECT detail_id
                                                     FROM details
                                                    WHERE Country = 'B'
                                                    LIMIT 1),
                                                  'Some State');
```

Comment: Would have to add an `detail_id` column to `Details`

Comment: Phil: I'm assuming Details have a primary key (and most of the time, it's an auto-incremented integer), but it doesn't have to be.

Comment: OP says it only has two columns, `Name` and `Country`. Adding an ID would be a good idea though difficult to do after data has already been inserted